# Abbreviation to State Name Function

Tags: r

I am trying to create a function to convert abbreviation to state name

Ex: CA => California

```
abb_to_name <- function(abbr){
  x <- state.name[str_which(state.abb, toupper(abbr))]
  return(x)
}
abb_to_name("CA")
#[1] "California"
```

This is what I go so far. The result is not 100% as expected. But when I pass a vector, it returns:

```
abb_to_name(c("CA","AL"))
#[1] "California"
```

However, when I apply for the data frame, I need to apply `map()` to get the expected result:

```
ex <- data.frame(STATE = c("AL", "CA", "NC", "TX", "MN")) %>% 
  mutate(NAMES = map(STATE, abb_to_name))
```

How can I fix the function above and the result can be return as my expectation:

**OUTPUT**:

```
abb_to_name(c("CA","AL"))
#[1] "California" “Alabama”
```

Comment: You need vectorize i.e. `Vectorize(abb_to_name)(c("CA", "AL"))` The `str_which` `pattern` can be regex single pattern and is not vectorized `str_which(state.abb, toupper(c("CA", "AL")))#
[1] 5`

Comment: Another option is to use `which` and `%in%`. Something like `x <- state.name[which(state.abb %in% toupper(abbr))]`

Comment: Thank @akrun and nniloc, let' me try

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It makes sense to do something like this using indexing.  Unfortunately, the state names aren't indexed by the abbreviations, but it's easy to fix that:

```r
abb_to_name <- function(abbr) {
  names(state.name) <- state.abb
  state.name[abbr]
}

abb_to_name(c("CA","AL"))
#>           CA           AL 
#> "California"    "Alabama"
```

This doesn't exactly match what you asked for, because it returns a named vector.  This version fixes that:

```r
abb_to_name <- function(abbr) {
  names(state.name) <- state.abb
  unname(state.name[abbr])
}

abb_to_name(c("CA","AL"))
#> [1] "California" "Alabama"
```

<sup>Created on 2022-10-07 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

Edited to add:  If this is going in a package, I'd
only set the names once, rather than every time the function is called.  For example,

```r
# This creates a package-local copy of state.name
names(state.name) <- state.abb

abb_to_name <- function(abbr) {
  state.name[abbr]
}
```

Comment: you truly get the point for the added part. Big Thanks!